# Slow mail with MTA

Tags: php, email, email-server

I am using PHP to send mail. I've tried both the native php function and the php mailer and I have excluded that it would be PHP causing the sluggish and slow behavior. My issue is that it takes several seconds for my debian server to send one mail which is unacceptable when sending several of them.

Nothing is configured on the machine, only php and nginx. For some reason the mail.log, syslog or the defined /var/log/phpmail.log is empty(yes, permissions are set to 777 for testing).

I have very little experience with these kind of issues so am asking for help and advice of how to speed up this process. Could it be the local MTA acting slow?

What would be the next step forward, 
Help appreciated.

Here is the sendmail log that appears maybe 10 seconds after PHP send it:

```
Feb  3 11:59:01 mycomputer sendmail[7050]: s13Ax1wI007050: from=root, size=582, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201402031059.s13Ax1wI007050@mycomputer>, relay=root@localhost
Feb  3 11:59:01 mycomputer sm-mta[7051]: s13Ax1fC007051: from=<root@mycomputer>, size=820, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201402031059.s13Ax1wI007050@mycomputer>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Feb  3 11:59:01 mycomputer sendmail[7050]: s13Ax1wI007050: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30582, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s13Ax1fC007051 Message accepted for delivery)
Feb  3 11:59:01 mycomputer sm-mta[7052]: s13Ax1fC007051: to=foo, ctladdr=<root@mycomputer> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31012, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Feb  3 11:59:02 mycomputer sendmail[7054]: s13Ax2Kv007054: from=root, size=577, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201402031059.s13Ax2Kv007054@mycomputer>, relay=root@localhost
Feb  3 11:59:02 mycomputer sm-mta[7055]: s13Ax24Y007055: from=<root@mycomputer>, size=815, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201402031059.s13Ax2Kv007054@mycomputer>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Feb  3 11:59:02 mycomputer sendmail[7054]: s13Ax2Kv007054: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30577, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s13Ax24Y007055 Message accepted for delivery)
Feb  3 11:59:02 mycomputer sm-mta[7056]: s13Ax24Y007055: to=foo, ctladdr=<root@mycomputer> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31007, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Comment: You need to make sure the mailer or MTA has a good DNS server available, most delays of this type are due to slow name lookups.

Comment: Ok, I installed sendmail to replace the original one. Will the mail package use the same DNS as specified in /etc/network/interfaces? I have 8.8.8.8 as primary DNS.

Comment: I have updated my post with a mail.log entry

Comment: Also having a goodly set up FQDN on your IPs is needed for sendmail to function properly. Do you have a log entry that has a mail sent by php? These are sent by the system.

Comment: The mail appear in my inbox before it is outputted in mail.log

Comment: As Semirke says, make sure your server has a proper FQDN: http://symbiotix.net/articles/sendmail-60-second-delay

Comment: I tried the sendmail -v you@yoursite.com < sample.msg and it was blazing fast. How is that possible?

Comment: What does the log show, is it as always a connection from localhost?

Comment: Have you actually tested sending several mails or are you only measuring the performance of a single mail at a time? Perhaps sending one takes the same time as sending 1000? Try to test with what you expect to be a 'real world' scenario.